# Sorting and Ranking values of columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have 3 columns and 3 rows, the first column is for ID, the second is names, third is votes. like:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | votes |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | bob  |     7 |
|  2 | jill |     2 |
|  3 | jake |     9 |
+----+------+-------+
```

How can I have PHP compare the values in the votes field and sort it by whichever had the highest number, and attach a rank of #1,2,3, etc. depending on how many votes it had?

Each value will be displayed on a separate page. For example, if I went to 'bob's page' with the ID of 1, I would need it to display '#2 bob' since he would be ranked 2nd by votes.

Comment: you would do it with mysql, SELECT ... ORDER BY votes

Answer (score 1):

You can make a separate column rank and update it by running the following code whenever your vote changes. This method will make you more efficient as in this you wont be sorting the table again and again when user visits his page:

```
    $q = "select * from tableName order by votes DESC";
    $a = mysql_query($q);
    $count = 1;
    while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($a){
       $up = "update tableName set(rank) VALUES($count) WHERE name=$arr['name']";
       $aq = mysql_query($up);
       $count++;
    }
```

Now on individual pages, you can just retrieve the rank value and show

```
$user = "Bob";
$q = "select rank from tableName where name=$user";
$a = mysql_query($q);
$arr = mysql_fetch_array($a);
echo $arr[0];
```

Also this(a slight modification in other answer) should work for you :-

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rank, name, vote FROM table, (SELECT @rownum:=0) as P ORDER BY vote DESC
```

Comment: that works for displaying them all on the same page, i should of elaborated more in my post. each value will be displayed on a separate page. if i went to 'bobs page' with the ID of 1 i need it to display '#2 bob' since he would be ranked 2nd by votes etc..

Comment: @user1781809 I have updated the answer. This should efficiently solve your issue

Comment: @user1781809 This should be a copy paste now

Answer (score 0):

You could read the values returned by your query into an array and then sort said array.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `SELECT` query doing an `ORDER BY` votes, and create a special variable to handle the rank of a row:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rank, name, vote FROM table, (SELECT @rownum:=0) ORDER BY vote DESC
```

This query should let you fetch an array with the rank, name, and number of votes of each person of your table.

Alternatively, you can just sort by vote, and add the rank value yourself with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL 'ORDER BY' and display those ranks using PHP:
For this example:

```
<?php
//connection
//DB selection
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_votes ORDER BY votes DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

for(int $i=1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);i++)
{
    echo "#".$i.$row['name']."<br/>";
}
?>
```